# Let $X$ be any set $\tau : = \{X-\{a_1 , a_2 ,......, a_n\} \cup \phi\}$. Is $(X , \tau )$ $T_1$?

Tags: general-topology

[image]
I can not understand the topology $\tau$. Can anyone please help me to understand?

Comment: Can you give more context? Also there should be a typo.

Comment: I have not been given any more information?  That is why I can not understand the Topology.. @Cornman

Comment: What are $a_1,\dotso, a_n$ for example? Your $\tau$ is not even a topology, if you note it like this. Because $X$ is not an element. Neither is $\emptyset$, but this should be a typo.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\tau : = \{X-\{a_1 , a_2 ,......, a_n\}|n\in\mathbb{N},a_,\cdots,a_n\in X\}  \cup\{ \emptyset\}$.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please take a look.@Cornman

Comment: I think so @tkf

Comment: Notice how adding the parentheses around $\emptyset$ completely changes the meaning of the question between what you wrote and what is written in the image.  However even in the image, it is not clear what $\{a_1 , a_2 ,......, a_n\} \}$ means.  The most reasonable interpretation is the one I gave.

Comment: I am sure that $n$ is not specific.@tkf

Comment: Good, now you understand what the topology is, do you still need help determining if the $T_0,T_1,T_2$ conditions hold?  Perhaps have a think about it and see which ones you can decide on, and then post a comment if you are still stuck.

Comment: If the $X$ is finite then the topology $(X , \tau )$ will be $T_0 , T_1 , T_2$ and when the $X$ is infinite then the topology $(X , \tau )$ will be $T_1  , T_0$. Am I correct?@tkf

Comment: Hiii @tkf am I correct?

Comment: Great that is correct - not $T_2$ if $X$ infinite.  The issue here was just that the question was not written down clearly which was not your fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology that is meant is most likely:

$$\tau = \{X\setminus F\mid F\subseteq X\text{ finite }\} \cup \{\emptyset\}$$

And a topology on $X$ is $T_1$ iff for all $x \in X$, $\{x\}$ is closed. Now decide... Whether $X$ is a $T_2$ space will depend on the size of $X$..

Comment: If the X is finite then the topology (X,τ) will be T0,T1,T2 and when the X is infinite then the topology (X,τ) will be T1,T0. Am I correct?@Henno

Comment: @sani indeed, but you have to prove it.

Comment: I can prove it. @Henno